# sh: 1: nuxt: not found (Heroku/Nuxt)

Tags: vue.js, express, heroku, nuxt.js

I've got a problem, I'm finally deploying a server-side nuxt app (with an express server) I've created to Heroku. The build succeeds but then when it tries to start it gives me:

```
2021-07-29T18:13:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-07-29T18:13:42.050534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-07-29T18:13:42.139623+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-29T18:13:41.793565+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-29T18:13:41.793587+00:00 app[web.1]: > nuxt-express@1.0.0 start /app
2021-07-29T18:13:41.793588+00:00 app[web.1]: > nuxt start
2021-07-29T18:13:41.793588+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-29T18:13:41.814774+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nuxt: not found
2021-07-29T18:13:41.822159+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-07-29T18:13:41.822579+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-07-29T18:13:41.822774+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-07-29T18:13:41.823001+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-07-29T18:13:41.834748+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! nuxt-express@1.0.0 start: `nuxt start`
2021-07-29T18:13:41.834966+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-07-29T18:13:41.835206+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-07-29T18:13:41.835433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the nuxt-express@1.0.0 start script.
```

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong with this. Do I have to build it before deploying with the Heroku cli? Is it a problem with my express server (since it's saying it failed at nuxt-express. I'm just not sure whats going on, if anyone could be of help it would greatly assist me! Thanks!

Here is my **package.json** if it helps:

```json
{
    "name": "p-live",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
    },
    "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/http": "latest",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^7.5.0",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "latest",
    "firebase": "^8.3.1",
    "jsforce": "^1.10.1",
    "nuxt": "latest"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.6.1",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^3.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/custom-forms": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your start script to be a path to `nuxt/bin` then provide the

Optionally if you still are having issues, consider adding the `-c` flag with the relative path to your `nuxt.config.js` file.

Do the same for build.

```json
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
```

to

```json
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js build -c ./nuxt.config.js",
    "start": "node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js start -c ./nuxt.config.js",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
```